# Is opening multiple cursors in Mysql a costly operation using Python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, stored-procedures, mysql-python

I have few tables in Mysql which are to be loaded into Teradata, I am going with file based approach here, Meaning I export Mysql tables into delimiter file and those files i'm trying to load into teradata. The question/clarity i am expecting is, We are maintaining Mysql stored procedure to extract the data from tables, this stored procedure i'm using in python script to fetch the table data. Is it good/optimal to use stored procedure. Because to get the list of tables, retention period, datebase and other details, i'm creating one cursor to fetch data from 1 table, and again i have to create another cursor to call stored procedure.

1. Is it a costly operation in mysql creating a cursor.
2. Instead of table to fetch list of tables, retention period, datebase and other details, is it good thought to maintain them in flat file.

Please share your thoughts.

```py
import sys
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
import csv

output_file_path='/home/XXXXXXX/'
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/XXXXXXX/')

from mysql_config import *

def stored_proc_call(tbl):


    print('SP call:', tbl)
    conn_sp = mysql.connector.connect(host=dsn,database=database,user=username,passwd=password,allow_local_infile=True)
    conn_sp_cursor = conn_sp.cursor(buffered=True)
    conn_sp_cursor.callproc('mysql_stored_proc', [tbl])

    output_file = output_file_path + tbl + '.txt'
    print('output_file:', output_file)
    with open(output_file, 'w') as filehandle:
         writer = csv.writer(filehandle, delimiter='\x10')
         for result in conn_sp_cursor.stored_results():
             print('Stored proc cursor:{}, value:{}'.format(type(result), result))
             for row in result:
                 writer.writerow(row)
                 #print('cursor row', row)

# Allow loading client-side files using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement.
con = mysql.connector.connect(host=dsn,database=database,user=username,passwd=password,allow_local_infile=True)
cursor = con.cursor(buffered=True)

cursor.execute("select * from table")

for row in cursor:
    print('Archive table cursor:{}, value:{}'.format(type(row), row))
    (db,table,col,orgid,*allvalues)=row
    stored_proc_call(table)
    #print('db:{}, table:{}, col:{}, orgid:{}, ret_period:{}, allvalues:{}'.format(db,table,col,orgid,ret_period,allvalues))

#print('db:{}, table:{}, col:{}, orgid:{}, ret_period:{}, allvalues:{}'.format(db,table,col,orgid,ret_period,allvalues))
```

Comment: I assume you mean a python cursor (e.g. `conn.cursor()`)? That is the default way to get data from a MySQL server. Same for maintaining a table list: asking the server which tables there are is the default way to find out which tables there are (if you don't know them). MySQL can handle 1000s of requests like this. That is its job, so don't underestimate it. If *your* code/implementation/way to export is fine or may be a problem: we don't know without seeing your code. Also: do you actually have a problem/issue (e.g. is it too slow, do other queries time out during export, ...)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, i'm talking about python cursor. I was wondering creating multiple cursors is an optimal way. Since you already mentioned 1000s of such requests can be handled by mysql. I am fine here. I'm not seeing any big delay in executing the python script which exports nearly 10tables avg row size is 10000 for each table. All i am expecting is an expert opinion what i'm doing is correct.

Comment: As I said, we cannot tell you if what you are doing is correct without seeing your code, but it sounds as if you are in the right direction (although I don't really know about your stored procedures, wouldn't be my first guess). Feel free to ask (with code) if you run into problems (or if you just want to know if you are on the right track). If you got your code working fine, but want an opinion about it, you can try the sister site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (again, with code).

Comment: Thanks for the codereview site details., By the way i am including the code i have written.